# How do i add my own image to a button that links to another website in HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, button

I'm trying to create a button that links to another website and I want to add my own image to it. 
should I use the `<input>` tag or the `<button>` tag?
Thank you!

Comment: Should i use the BUTTON TAG or the INPUT tag**

Comment: I'm sure you need to use the tag. :) Seriously, please format the code as 'the tag' looks pretty strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add a link to another website, then, you need to use the a href tag and since you want to add an image as a link, then, you need to add the img tag inside the a href tag like the below given code:

```
<a href="Your Destined Page"><img src="Your Desired Image"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an HTML form :

```
<form action="http://yoursite.com">
    <input type="submit" value=" to your site">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you want you can use.

You can use a button or input as well and give it a background (either color or image)
Check this out

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/foqawetapo/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
<button type="button" id="button1">My Button with image in background</button>

#button1 {
  -webkit-appearance : none;
  -moz-appearance : none;
  border : none;
  background : url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f2/Core_Image_icon.png/96px-Core_Image_icon.png');
  background-size : 100% 100%;
  background-repeat : no-repeat;
  width : 200px;
  height : 100px;
  box-shadow : 2px 2px 2px 1px gray;
}
```